# Flatten nested iterables

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I wrote a program sometime ago that reads csv files, sorts, reorders and groups their columns/rows' content (with `itertools`) and later labels the groups using a dictionary. The groups and dictionary are then flattened and rows of length N (columns) are uploaded to a spreadsheet. This is another function, not specific to that program, to use in this situation.

```
def digfrom(iterable, *, depth=None, strings=True):
    """
    Dig values from nested iterables, flattening
    the input iterable.

        >>> iterable = [['a'], 'bc', ('de', ['f'])]

        >>> list(digfrom(iterable))
        ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']


    Depth may be limited and "exploding" strings
    is optional.

        >>> list(digfrom(iterable, depth=2))
        ['a', 'b', 'c']

        >>> list(digfrom(iterable, strings=False))
        ['a', 'bc', 'de', 'f']


    """

    exhausted = object()
    iterable_attr = '__iter__'
    iterator_attr = '__next__'

    iterators = [iter(iterable)]

    while iterators:
        it = next(iterators[-1], exhausted)

        if it is exhausted:
            iterators.pop()
            continue

        if hasattr(it, iterable_attr):
            string = isinstance(it, str)

            if not ((string and len(it) <= 1) or
                    (string and not strings)):
                it = iter(it)

        if hasattr(it, iterator_attr):
            iterators.append(it)
            iterators = iterators[:depth]
        else:
            yield it
```

Comment: Downvote. So it's no good I guess. Was just looking for a nudge to redo that awful program I mentioned. Maybe I should've talked about the code, although it seems small and simple enough not to warrant a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Take a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask - please always include all of your code and a description of what you're doing and why you're doing it.

Comment: @Raystafarian OP already included a description of the code (albeit somewhat short). There's no need for additional information here. Taking one function from a program to get it reviewed is okay as far as I'm aware. The help center only states that the code presented must work as expected, which it does.

Comment: @Coal_ I was responding to the comment about the downvote - I didn't vote but thought maybe that would help. I really don't like downvotes with no comment :/ Either way the post indicates there are more functions, which aren't included.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like decent code. I think you only got downvoted (once) because you alluded to how you wanted to use this function as part of a (gasp!) program — and then of course twice more because [they saw you'd already been downvoted once](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwagon_effect). That's just how this site works. :)

---

The biggest problem with your code is that it uses the identifiers `iterable`, `iterable_attr`, `iterator_attr`, `iterators`, `it`, and `iter`, all with different meanings. That's too many `it`s!

`iterable_attr` and `iterator_attr` could be called more like `ITER_ATTR` and `NEXT_ATTR`, because (A) the capitalization indicates that they're constants, and (B) the names indicate the values they hold. However, this is right up there with `THREE = 3`. When you see yourself giving symbolic names to global constants, it's time to [DRY up your code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```
    if hasattr(it, '__iter__'):
        string = isinstance(it, str)
        if not ((string and len(it) <= 1) or
                (string and not strings)):
            it = iter(it)
    if hasattr(it, '__next__'):
        iterators.append(it)
        iterators = iterators[:depth]
```

---

Actually, that logical expression buried in the middle there looks like it could stand some [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). Also, `string` is a bad name for a boolean! Name your booleans after predicates: in this case, `is_string` would do. But let's see if we need it at all.

```
        is_string = isinstance(it, str)
        if not ((is_string and len(it) <= 1) or (is_string and not strings)):
            it = iter(it)
```

De Morgan 1:

```
        is_string = isinstance(it, str)
        if not(is_string and len(it) <= 1) and not(is_string and not strings):
            it = iter(it)
```

De Morgan 2:

```
        isnt_string = not isinstance(it, str)
        if (isnt_string or len(it) > 1) and (isnt_string or strings):
            it = iter(it)
```

Distributive law:

```
        isnt_string = not isinstance(it, str)
        if isnt_string or (strings and len(it) > 1):
            it = iter(it)
```

Refactor to emphasize the one special case we're trying to express:

```
        if (not hasattr(it, '__iter__')) or (len(it) <= 1):
            pass  # can't explode this guy
        elif (not strings) and isinstance(it, str):
            pass  # we're not exploding strings
        else:
            it = iter(it)  # explode it
```

---

The next two lines

```
        iterators.append(it)
        iterators = iterators[:depth]
```

look suspicious. We're appending to the array and then immediately truncating it? Couldn't we do that in some cleaner way?

---

By the way, that `*,` in the signature must be a Python-3-ism; I'm not sure what it means. In Python 2 you'd just omit it and it would still do what you wanted.

---

Your `exhausted = object()` ... `if it is exhausted` idiom is neat, if *maybe* a bit too cute. It beats catching the exception from `next(iterators[-1])`, anyway.

---

Unit tests (especially for `depth=...`) would go a long way here.

Comment: The single star in the arguments is [PEP3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/).